# Generate headings from a Jekyll Collection item's front-matter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

As you see below, this is a fairly simple collection setup with an unordered lists of events that live in the `_events` folder at the root level (output is set to false). Instead of using `{{ page.title }}` in the layout, I want the heading(s) to read as months.

For example, if I add a new item into the `_events` collection and include `month: January` in the front-matter, I want that to generate a “January” heading, and place that unordered list underneath the heading. Likewise, if I add a new collection item and include `month: February` in the front-matter, I want to generate a “February” heading with a new unordered list below that heading.

I know I need a bit of re-arranging of where the heading lives, and I'm thinking I need some type of `if` statement, but I’m at a roadblock. I can’t figure this one out.

Is this possible with Jekyll Collections?

Layout

```
{% include root.html %}

<div class="flex-main">
    {% include header.html %}
    <main class="o-main" role="main">
        <div class="o-grid-six">
          <h1 class="f1 o-grid-six__child c-headline">{{ page.title }}</h1>
        </div>
        {{ content }}
    </main>
</div>

<div class="flex-footer">
    {% include footer.html %}
</div>
```

View (Events)

```
---
layout: events
title: Events
order: 2
---
<ul class="c-event-list">
  {% for events in site.events %}
  <li class="c-event-list__flag">
      <div class="c-event-list__flag--left">
        <div class="c-event-list__calendar">
          <span class="c-event-list__day">{{ events.weekday }}</span>
          <span class="f2 c-event-list__date">{{ events.date-number }}</span>
        </div>
        <img class="c-event-list__image" src="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}{{ events.thumb }}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="c-event-list__flag--body">
        <div class="c-event-list__content">
          <h3 class="f2 c-event-list__title">{{ events.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ events.description }}</p>
          <a class="c-button u-mt-2" href="{{ events.link }}">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Collection item (an event)

```
---
layout: default
thumb: /images/event__screen-printing-basics.jpg
link: https://www.eventbrite.com/e/screen-printing-basics-tickets-41882948025
title: Screen Printing Basics
weekday: Wednesday
month: January
date-number: '10'
description: Join us for an after hours session to learn everything you need to know about screen printing in the Make Lab. We will be coating screens with emulsion, printing artwork onto transparencies, burning the image into the screen, washing out the stencil, mixing ink, prepping our work station, registering the paper, and finally pulling prints. The artwork always varies, so you’ll leave with a one-of-a-kind screen printed poster that you made yourself!
---
```

Interface
[image: Events View]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to use real `dateTime` and `group_by_exp` filter.

### DateTime

```
---
layout: default
thumb: /images/event__screen-printing-basics.jpg
link: ...
title: Screen Printing Basics
description: ...
date: 2018-03-21 20:00
---
```

Note that for some reason `date: 2018-03-21` doesn't work.

### group_by_exp filter

Simplified print logic can be :

```
{% assign eventsByYear = site.events | group_by_exp:"event", "event.date | date: '%Y'" %}
{% for year in eventsByYear %}
  <h1>{{ year.name }}</h1>
  {% assign eventsByMonth = year.items | group_by_exp:"event", "event.date | date: '%B'" %}
  {% for month in eventsByMonth %}
    <h2>{{ month.name }}</h2>
    <ul>
      {% for event in month.items %}
        <li>{{ event.title }}-{{ event.date | date: "%A, %B %d, %Y"}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```